# Facebook url posting gives 404

Tags: facebook, http-status-code-404

We have some url of the below form which is giving 404 while trying to posting in facebook status. In the browser it works fine.

https://au.tv.yahoo.com/plus7/married-with-children/-/watch/29973062/married-with-children-wed-4-nov-season-3-episode-7/

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reproduce this. I did however checked the url first on developers.facebook.com/tools/debug. This URL had never been scraped.